# What can be an Open source Replacement to Amazon S3?

Tags: apache, hadoop, amazon-web-services, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I want a distributed , highly available storage for files but not on cloud.
What are the open source alternatives i have ?

One option is simple file server with apache, but thats not highly available.

I found one https://code.google.com/p/mogilefs/

Is there something better ? Have anyone used mogilefs before ?

Is it perfect replacement of S3 , my basic requirement is to upload and download files.
Upload tps might be high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [HDFS](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable1/hdfs_design.html) .Its is highly fault-tolerant and is designed to be deployed on low-cost hardware. HDFS provides high throughput access to application data and is suitable for applications that have large data sets. HDFS is now an Apache Hadoop subproject. The project URL is [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/).

Comment: HDFS has i guess single point of failure , i am considering something which is HA

Comment: you can get HA with HDFS with additional configuration. http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithNFS.html

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop [HDFS can be accessed also over HTTP](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-hdfs-httpfs/index.html). This should be what you are exactly looking for - a replicated distributed filesystem (HDFS) on the base and can access it over HTTP like S3